Perf only has power/energy-pkg
I am currently using
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5800x3D
Kernel: 6.9.6-zen1-1
Perf version: 6.9.2
and I am trying to use perf stat -e power/energy-ram but upon checking /sys/bus/event_source/devices/power/events I can only see energy-pkg. How do I go about getting the rest of power/? Is there a way to tell if there is support for my CPU. Not sure if my google fu is weak but I can't seem to find anything to this.
Thanks!
ls /sys/bus/event_source/devices/power/events
.r--r--r-- 4.1k root 24 Jun 04:36  energy-pkg
.r--r--r-- 4.1k root 24 Jun 04:36  energy-pkg.scale
.r--r--r-- 4.1k root 24 Jun 04:36  energy-pkg.unit


If your Zen 3 even has hardware to measure DRAM power/energy, it seems Linux doesn't know how to read it.  The details of performance counters and energy counters are very specific to the CPU. Modern Intel CPUs support events like power/energy-ram (as shown in I can't see perf's power/energy-cores option for measure power consumption for example), but I wouldn't be surprised if AMD simply doesn't put that feature in their hardware.
